# Configuring DataSources with IDEA IntelliJ Jetty Plugin (jetty-env.xml)

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, jndi

I'm trying to getting started with the IDEA IntelliJ Jetty Plugin. In our application we use a JNDI DataSource to access the actual database.

For development therefore we generate a *jetty-env.xml* and include this in the *WEB-INF* directory during development deploys:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <!-- Add an JNDI resource -->
  <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>datasource_pbv</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="DriverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</Set>
                <Set name="Url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbserver:1521:DATABASE</Set>
                <Set name="Username">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

I reconfigured the Jetty *WebAppDeployer* in *jetty.xml* that way, so it uses the *org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration* which reads and processes the *jetty-env.xml*:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">  
    ...
    <Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration</Item>
      <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
    </Array>
    ...
    <Call name="addLifeCycle">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
            ...              
            <Set name="configurationClasses"><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
    ...
</Configure>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with the IDEA Jetty plugin. The IDEA Jetty Plugin generates a *context-config.xml* and a subsequent *war-exploded.xml* which does not add the EnvConfiguration. **Therefore the jetty-env.xml is ignored when deploying with the Jetty IDEA Plugin.**

How can I make this work or are the other ways to provide custom JNDI entries when deploying using the IDEA Jetty Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked myself, but since IDEA Jetty integration relies on `ContextDeployer`, the following should work (if added to `jetty.xml`):

```
<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.ContextDeployer">
        ...              
        <Set name="configurationClasses"><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```